Limit behaviour of a distribution
Consider the distribution, with $a>0,p>0$
$$
F(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}\frac{J_2(a\sqrt{p^2-x^2})}{x- p} & -p<x<p \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{matrix}\right.
$$
I claim that $F$ approximates a Dirac delta in the high $p$ limit, because $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty} F(x) = 0$ except at $x=p$, and
$$\int_{-p}^{p} F(x) dx = \frac{a^2 p^2-2 a p \sin (a p)-2 \cos (a p)+2}{a^2 p^2} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
which is 1 in the high $p$ limit.
Thus, for some suitably well-behaved test function $f$,
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty} \left(f(p)-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x) f(x) dx \right) = 0$$
In other words,
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty} F(x) = \delta(x-p)$$
Numerical experiments confirm this.
Question: I am interested in characterizing the high-$p$ limit behaviour of
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty} p(F(x)-\delta(x-p)) \tag{2}\label{2}  $$
The $1/p$ term in \eqref{1} certainly suggests that \eqref{2} does not vanish.
